# Find list of Distinct string Values stored in a field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have stored my data in elasticsearch  which is as given below. It returns only distinct words in the given field and not the entire distinct phrase.

```
    {
    "_index" : "test01",
    "_type" : "whatever01",
    "_id" : "1234",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "company_name" : "State Bank of India",
      "user" : ""
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test01",
    "_type" : "whatever01",
    "_id" : "5678",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "company_name" : "State Bank of India",
      "user" : ""
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test01",
    "_type" : "whatever01",
    "_id" : "8901",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "company_name" : "Kotak Mahindra Bank",
      "user" : ""
    }
  }
```

I tried using Term Aggregation Function

```
    GET /test01/_search/
    {
        "aggs" : {
        "genres":
            {
               "terms" : 
                     { "field": "company_name"} 
             }
          }
    }
```

I get the following output

```
    "aggregations" : {
"genres" : {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count" : 10531,
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : "bank",
      "doc_count" : 2818
    },
    {
      "key" : "mahindra",
      "doc_count" : 1641
    },
    {
      "key" : "state",
      "doc_count" : 1504
    }]
```

}}

How to get the entire string in the field "company_name" with only distinct values as given below?

```
    "aggregations" : {
"genres" : {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count" : 10531,
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : "Kotak Mahindra Bank",
      "doc_count" : 2818
    },
    {
      "key" : "State Bank of India",
      "doc_count" : 1641
    }
    ]
```

}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you've set `"fielddata": "true"` for your field `company_name` which is of type `text`. This is not good as it can end up consuming lot of heap space as mentioned in this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#_fielddata_is_disabled_on_literal_text_literal_fields_by_default).

Further more, the *field's values* of type `text` are broken down into tokens and is saved in inverted index using a process called [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html). Setting `fielddata` on fields of type text would cause the aggregation to work as what you mentioned in your question.

What you'd need to do is create its sibling equivalent of type [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) as mentioned in this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#multi-fields) and perform aggregation on that field.

Basically modify your mapping for `company_name` as below:

### Mapping:

```
PUT <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "mappings": {
    "mydocs": {
      "properties": {
        "company_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Run the below aggregation query on this `company_name.keyword` field and you'd get what you are looking for.

## Query:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "unique_names": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "company_name.keyword",        <----- Run on this field
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!